# POST in AWS API getting 400 error while testing POST

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, post

I am trying to test POST method in my API gateway and i am getting error:

> {"message": "Could not parse request body into json: Unexpected
>   character (\'}\' (code 125)): expected a value\n at [Source:
>   [B@11a9cb82; line: 5, column: 2]"}

the request body i am using:

```
"{\"DataTypes\":\"ADL\"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should not escape anything.
If you try with

```
{"DataTypes": "ADL"}
```

it should work.